# Is there a useDirtyFlag option for Tomcat 6 cluster configuration?

Tags: java, session, replication, tomcat6, cluster-computing

In Tomcat 5.0.x you had the ability to set useDirtyFlag="false" to *force replication of the session after every request* rather than checking for set/removeAttribute calls.

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.cluster.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                 managerClassName="org.apache.catalina.cluster.session.SimpleTcpReplicationManager"
                 expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                 **useDirtyFlag="false"**
                 doClusterLog="true"
                 clusterLogName="clusterLog"> ...
```

The comments in the server.xml stated this may be used to make the following work:

```
<%
    HashMap map = (HashMap)session.getAttribute("map");
    map.put("key","value");
%>
```

i.e. change the state of an object that has *already been put in the session* and you can be sure that this object still be replicated to the other nodes in the cluster.

According to the Tomcat 6 documentation you only have two "Manager" options - DeltaManager & BackupManager ... neither of these seem to allow this option or anything like it. In my testing the default setup:

```
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
```

where you get the DeltaManager by default, it's definitely behaving as useDirtyFlag="true" (as I'd expect).

So my question is - is there an equivalent in Tomcat 6?

Looking at the source I can see a manager implementation "org.apache.catalina.ha.session.SimpleTcpReplicationManager" which does have the useDirtyFlag but the javadoc comments in this state it's "Tomcat Session Replication for Tomcat 4.0" ... I don't know if this is ok to use - I'm guessing not as it's not mentioned in the main cluster configuration documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted essentially the same question on the tomcat-users mailing list and the responses to this along with some information in the tomcat bugzilla ([43866]) led me to the following conclusions:

1. There is no equivalent to the useDirtyFlag, if you're putting mutable (ie changing) objects in the session you need a custom coded solution.
2. A Tomcat ClusterValve seems to be an effecting place for this solution - plug into the cluster mechanism, manipulate attributes to make it appear to the DeltaManager that all attributes in the session have changed. This forces replication of the entire session.

**Step 1: Write the `ForceReplicationValve` (extends `ValveBase` implements `ClusterValve`)**

I won't include the whole class but the key bit of logic (taking out the logging and instanceof checking):

```
@Override
public void invoke(Request request, Response response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    getNext().invoke(request, response);
    Session session = request.getSessionInternal();        
    HttpSession deltaSession = (HttpSession) session;
    for (Enumeration<String> names = deltaSession.getAttributeNames(); 
            names.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        String name = names.nextElement();
        deltaSession.setAttribute(name, deltaSession.getAttribute(name));
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Alter the cluster config (in `conf/server.xml`)**

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
            channelSendOptions="8">        
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ForceReplicationValve"/>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
          filter=".*\.gif;.*\.jpg;.*\.png;.*\.js;.*\.htm;.*\.html;.*\.txt;.*\.css;"/>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
</Cluster>
```

Replication of the session to all cluster nodes will now happen after every request.

Aside: Note the `channelSendOptions` setting. This replaces the `replicationMode=asynchronous/synchronous/pooled` from Tomcat 5.0.x. See the [cluster documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) for the possible int values.

**Appendix: Full Valve source as requested**

```
package org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;
import org.apache.catalina.Session;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.ha.CatalinaCluster;
import org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterValve;
import org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ReplicatedSession;
import org.apache.catalina.ha.session.SimpleTcpReplicationManager;
import org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport;
//import org.apache.catalina.util.StringManager;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;

/**
 * <p>With the {@link SimpleTcpReplicationManager} effectively deprecated, this allows
 * mutable objects to be replicated in the cluster by forcing the "dirty" status on 
 * every request.</p> 
 * 
 * @author Jon Brisbin (via post on tomcat-users http://markmail.org/thread/rdo3drcir75dzzrq)
 * @author Kevin Jansz
 */
public class ForceReplicationValve extends ValveBase implements Lifecycle, ClusterValve {
    private static org.apache.juli.logging.Log log =
        org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog( ForceReplicationValve.class );

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    protected static final String info = "org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ForceReplicationValve/1.0";

// this could be used if ForceReplicationValve messages were setup 
// in org/apache/catalina/ha/tcp/LocalStrings.properties
//    
//    /**
//     * The StringManager for this package.
//     */
//    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
//    protected static StringManager sm =
//        StringManager.getManager(Constants.Package);

    /** 
     * Not actually required but this must implement {@link ClusterValve} to 
     * be allowed to be added to the Cluster.
     */
    private CatalinaCluster cluster = null ;

    /**
     * Also not really required, implementing {@link Lifecycle} to allow 
     * initialisation and shutdown to be logged. 
     */
    protected LifecycleSupport lifecycle = new LifecycleSupport(this);    


    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ForceReplicationValve() {
        super();
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info(getInfo() + ": created");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException,
            ServletException {

        getNext().invoke(request, response);

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = request.getSessionInternal();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error(getInfo() + ": Unable to perform replication request.", e);
        }

        String context = request.getContext().getName();
        String task = request.getPathInfo();
        if(task == null) {
            task = request.getRequestURI();
        }
        if (session != null) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(getInfo() + ": [session=" + session.getId() + ", instanceof=" + session.getClass().getName() + ", context=" + context + ", request=" + task + "]");
            }
            if (session instanceof ReplicatedSession) {
                // it's a SimpleTcpReplicationManager - can just set to dirty
                ((ReplicatedSession) session).setIsDirty(true);
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    log.debug(getInfo() + ": [session=" + session.getId() + ", context=" + context + ", request=" + task + "] maked DIRTY");
                }
            } else {
                // for everything else - cycle all attributes
                List cycledNames = new LinkedList();

                // in a cluster where the app is <distributable/> this should be
                // org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaSession - implements HttpSession
                HttpSession deltaSession = (HttpSession) session;
                for (Enumeration<String> names = deltaSession.getAttributeNames(); names.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                    String name = names.nextElement();
                    deltaSession.setAttribute(name, deltaSession.getAttribute(name));

                    cycledNames.add(name);                    
                }

                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    log.debug(getInfo() + ": [session=" + session.getId() + ", context=" + context + ", request=" + task + "] cycled atrributes=" + cycledNames + "");
                }
            }
        } else {
            String id = request.getRequestedSessionId();
            log.warn(getInfo()  + ": [session=" + id + ", context=" + context + ", request=" + task + "] Session not available, unable to send session over cluster.");
        }
    }


    /* 
     * ClusterValve methods - implemented to ensure this valve is not ignored by Cluster  
     */

    public CatalinaCluster getCluster() {
        return cluster;
    }

    public void setCluster(CatalinaCluster cluster) {
        this.cluster = cluster;
    }


    /* 
     * Lifecycle methods - currently implemented just for logging startup 
     */

    /**
     * Add a lifecycle event listener to this component.
     *
     * @param listener The listener to add
     */
    public void addLifecycleListener(LifecycleListener listener) {
        lifecycle.addLifecycleListener(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Get the lifecycle listeners associated with this lifecycle. If this 
     * Lifecycle has no listeners registered, a zero-length array is returned.
     */
    public LifecycleListener[] findLifecycleListeners() {
        return lifecycle.findLifecycleListeners();
    }

    /**
     * Remove a lifecycle event listener from this component.
     *
     * @param listener The listener to remove
     */
    public void removeLifecycleListener(LifecycleListener listener) {
        lifecycle.removeLifecycleListener(listener);
    }

    public void start() throws LifecycleException {
        lifecycle.fireLifecycleEvent(START_EVENT, null);
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info(getInfo() + ": started");
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws LifecycleException {
        lifecycle.fireLifecycleEvent(STOP_EVENT, null);
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info(getInfo() + ": stopped");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The [how-to page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) says "For each request the entire session is replicated, this allows code that modifies attributes in the session without calling setAttribute or removeAttribute to be replicated". Doesn't that work or did I misunderstand the question/answer?

Comment: It seems like this comment was added after I posted this question ... it also says "a useDirtyFlag configuration parameter can be used to optimize the number of times a session is replicated".  This implies that there is a 'useDirtyFlag' that's off/false by default. I can't see any reference (in the docs or code) to confirm this though - my own testing (last year) did not get this behaviour.

Comment: Please  change this API of the above to session = request.getSessionInternal(false); . As default is true and it will try to create a session and throw an exception where session creation is not possible

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to [kevinjansz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166975/kevinjansz) for providing the source for ForceReplicationValve.

I adjusted it for Tomcat7, here it is if anyone needs it:

```
package org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;
import org.apache.catalina.Session;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.ha.CatalinaCluster;
import org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterValve;
import org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleState;
// import org.apache.tomcat.util.res.StringManager;

/**
 * <p>With the {@link SimpleTcpReplicationManager} effectively deprecated, this allows
 * mutable objects to be replicated in the cluster by forcing the "dirty" status on 
 * every request.</p> 
 * 
 * @author Jon Brisbin (via post on tomcat-users http://markmail.org/thread/rdo3drcir75dzzrq)
 * @author Kevin Jansz
 */
public class ForceReplicationValve extends ValveBase implements Lifecycle, ClusterValve {
    private static org.apache.juli.logging.Log log =
        org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog( ForceReplicationValve.class );

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    protected static final String info = "org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ForceReplicationValve/1.0";

// this could be used if ForceReplicationValve messages were setup 
// in org/apache/catalina/ha/tcp/LocalStrings.properties
//    
//    /**
//     * The StringManager for this package.
//     */
//    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
//    protected static StringManager sm =
//        StringManager.getManager(Constants.Package);

    /** 
     * Not actually required but this must implement {@link ClusterValve} to 
     * be allowed to be added to the Cluster.
     */
    private CatalinaCluster cluster = null;

    /**
     * Also not really required, implementing {@link Lifecycle} to allow 
     * initialisation and shutdown to be logged. 
     */
    protected LifecycleSupport lifecycle = new LifecycleSupport(this);    


    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ForceReplicationValve() {
        super();
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info(getInfo() + ": created");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException,
            ServletException {

        getNext().invoke(request, response);

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = request.getSessionInternal();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error(getInfo() + ": Unable to perform replication request.", e);
        }

        String context = request.getContext().getName();
        String task = request.getPathInfo();
        if(task == null) {
            task = request.getRequestURI();
        }
        if (session != null) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(getInfo() + ": [session=" + session.getId() + ", instanceof=" + session.getClass().getName() + ", context=" + context + ", request=" + task + "]");
            }
            //cycle all attributes
            List<String> cycledNames = new LinkedList<String>();

            // in a cluster where the app is <distributable/> this should be
            // org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaSession - implements HttpSession
            HttpSession deltaSession = (HttpSession) session;
            for (Enumeration<String> names = deltaSession.getAttributeNames(); names.hasMoreElements(); ) {
                String name = names.nextElement();
                deltaSession.setAttribute(name, deltaSession.getAttribute(name));

                cycledNames.add(name);                    
            }

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(getInfo() + ": [session=" + session.getId() + ", context=" + context + ", request=" + task + "] cycled atrributes=" + cycledNames + "");
            }
        } else {
            String id = request.getRequestedSessionId();
            log.warn(getInfo()  + ": [session=" + id + ", context=" + context + ", request=" + task + "] Session not available, unable to send session over cluster.");
        }
    }


    /* 
     * ClusterValve methods - implemented to ensure this valve is not ignored by Cluster  
     */

    public CatalinaCluster getCluster() {
        return cluster;
    }

    public void setCluster(CatalinaCluster cluster) {
        this.cluster = cluster;
    }


    /* 
     * Lifecycle methods - currently implemented just for logging startup 
     */

    /**
     * Add a lifecycle event listener to this component.
     *
     * @param listener The listener to add
     */
    public void addLifecycleListener(LifecycleListener listener) {
        lifecycle.addLifecycleListener(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Get the lifecycle listeners associated with this lifecycle. If this 
     * Lifecycle has no listeners registered, a zero-length array is returned.
     */
    public LifecycleListener[] findLifecycleListeners() {
        return lifecycle.findLifecycleListeners();
    }

    /**
     * Remove a lifecycle event listener from this component.
     *
     * @param listener The listener to remove
     */
    public void removeLifecycleListener(LifecycleListener listener) {
        lifecycle.removeLifecycleListener(listener);
    }

    protected synchronized void startInternal() throws LifecycleException {
        setState(LifecycleState.STARTING);
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info(getInfo() + ": started");
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void stopInternal() throws LifecycleException {
        setState(LifecycleState.STOPPING);
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info(getInfo() + ": stopped");
        }
    }

}
```