# get servlet context variable data in tomcat cluster environment

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Currently I am developing module to display list of online user in my application. I am using comet streaming technology. When users log in I put data in map and then sending data in message queue. Now message queue is stored in servlet context.

Now problem I am facing is it is working in local environment but it is not working in production environment because in production environment i have set up tomcat cluster. so data set in servlet context for tomcat 1 is not accessible in tomcat 2.

I have already develop module but not getting any way to solve above issue. I google and found that tomcat doesn't support context replication.

I have one doubt that how many JVM instance will be created in tomcat cluster web application. e.g I have two tomcat cluster.

Comment: Can you add your cluster configuration to your question.  I assume your are calling setAttribute on your servletContext then updating the attribute afterwards? Are you using tomcat 7?

Comment: ohh sorry i forgot to mention tomcat version, i am using tomcat 6. Yes i am using message queue and add it in context using setattribute if user gets online. I did configuration for context replication also in context.xml of tomcat server but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use servlet context to store data for a cluster. The common pattern is to use a database for data that must be shared across different servers.

For your use case, it is no need persisting the values between different runs, so the database is not necessarily a nice solution, even if it is easy to setup. IMHO what you need it just a shared data cache or better a memory data grid. [hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com/) should be easy to use for your requirements. If I correctly understand them, what you need is a distributed map, with a concatenation of node_id, session_id as key (or maybe simply session_id), and a user object as value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving suggestion. You saved my lot of time and my project :)

Comment: @shrey Thanks for the comment. Just another idea : do not forget to clean data if a node falls in the cluster ...

Comment: hazelcast taking lot of time while loading first time request in tomcat then everything is working fine. Do i need any configuration ?

Comment: I am not an expert on hazelcast. You can try to instanciate the distributed map in a context loader listener, or ask another question on SO for that.

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat7 this requires writing a custom valve to force replication, the same is true in tomcat 6. Refer to [Is there a useDirtyFlag option for Tomcat 6 cluster configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680958) to see how to do this.